# complicated json sort by a nested array and a passed key match

Tags: javascript, json

I have a relatively complex json object that I need to sort.

A simplified version looks like this.

### unsorted

```
[
  {
    "title": "title 1",
    "order": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "title 2",
    "order": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to sort this array based on matched ids and their associated position... For instance if I pass in the ID of 2, i would expect the sort order to be as follows because "title 2" has an id matched position of 0, whereas "title 1" has an id matched position of 1

### sorted by id match of 2

```
[
  {
    "title": "title 2",
    "order": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "title 1",
    "order": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I would think the function might need to look something like this, but am unable to figure out just how best to structure and sort this data.

```
const unsortedArray = //[json that needs to be sorted]

function sortArray(parentArray, sortArray, match){
  for(i in parentArray.sortArray){
   if(parentArray.sortArray[i].id == match){
    //use this position to sort by
   }
  }
}

sortArray(unsortedArray,order,1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit of code golf but lets see if I can explain.

You want to use the [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method. You give it a callback that takes two parameters: the elements to compare.

The goofy part is digging down in the element to find the position. That's where this happens `a.order.find(a => a.id === id).position`. You take the first element and get the order property that happens to be an array of ids. You use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the object with an id that matches the one that you are sorting by. When you get that object (like `{id: 2, position: 0}` you get the position. Do the same digging around in the second element to find the correct position.

Now you will have two integers to compare to tell the sort function which of the two goes first. Array.sort() expects a return value of *less than zero*, *zero*, or *greater than zero*. So you can subtract one position from the other and simply return the result.

Phew!

Hope that makes some sense.

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: "title 2",
    order: [
      {
        id: 2,
        position: 0
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        position: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "title 1",
    order: [
      {
        id: 1,
        position: 0
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        position: 1
      }
    ]
  }
];

const sort = (data, id) =>
  data.sort(
    (a, b) =>
      a.order.find(a => a.id === id).position -
      b.order.find(a => a.id === id).position
  );


console.log(sort(data, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const sampleArray = [
  {
    "title": "title 1",
    "order": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "title 2",
    "order": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "position": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "position": 1
      }
    ]
   }
]


const swap = (arr, idx1, idx2) => {
    [arr[idx1], arr[idx2]] = [arr[idx2], arr[idx1]];
};

sampleArray.forEach((item,index) => {
    if(item.order[0].id === 2) {
        swap(sampleArray,index,index-1)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, this line here `item.order[0].id === 2` however is problematic as it assumes that the item.order of position 0 will always be the proper reference.

Comment: then make that soring part as a function and you can pass the id as a parameter and sort it